# Load page / Cache analysis

Tags: html, browser-cache, cache-control

Hello all please help with the analysis of my page.

Question 1
Why since everything is load from cache. Load time is 690ms?

question 2 
what will be the reason to use --> private, max-age=60000

(public), max-age=60000  VS. private, max-age=60000

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, load time isn't just defined by the time it takes to get assets from the network. Painting and parsing can take a lot of time, as can the parsing of Javascript. In your case, `DOMContentLoaded` is only fired after 491 milliseconds, so that's already part of the answer.

As to your second question, the answer really is in the link you provided:

> If the response is marked as “public” then it can be cached, even if it has HTTP authentication associated with it, and even when the response status code isn’t normally cacheable. Most of the time, “public” isn’t necessary, because explicit caching information (like “max-age”) indicates that the response is cacheable anyway.
>
> By contrast, “private” responses can be cached by the browser but are typically intended for a single user and hence are not allowed to be cached by any intermediate cache - e.g. an HTML page with private user information can be cached by that user’s browser, but not by a CDN.

Comment: Thanks +1  I have other website which I down to 240ms a little disappointment   for the second question IF "private" will that avoid second hit like if you are using Azure Blob or Amazon S3 or Google Storage to AVOID storage transaction mean first time load from source but second load from client side...